# Разбить массив на подмассивы вывести их сумму

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с 5 чисел

```
const Arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Надо написать функцию которая принимает массив Arr и некоторое число k (длина подмассива). Функция перебирает все возможные комбинации подмассива например [1,2,3]; [1,2,4]; [1,2,5] и тд и выводит сумму каждого подмассива.
Вообщем нужно посчитать все возможные суммы 3х чисел

Comment: Кортежи в Python, в JS такого нет, может вы языком ошиблись?

Comment: @Leonid, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: @entithat - в JS нет упорядоченных наборов фиксированной длины. Array, Set, Map, WeakMap, WeakSet не могут быть названы таковыми. Неизменяемые массивы - кортежи - есть в Python (Tuple).

Comment: исправил название и текст

Comment: @Leonid, следуя вашему первому предложению в питоне, мне кажется, таковых тоже нет. Комментарий звучал так: "у меня есть молоток, но я хочу сделать булочки". А формального обозначения питоновских таплов в джс нет, согласен.

Comment: @entithat суть была в том, что **местом ошиблись**)) Может в Питоне кто-то возьмется за такое задание))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будем использовать рекурсию и `Set()`, чтобы убрать дубликаты. Тут надо думать с конца. Проходимся по каждому массиву, который вернёт нам функция `comb()`. Дальше проходимся по каждому элементу нашего исходного массива и если такое значение уже есть в массиве (полученного с `comb()`), то пропускаем эту итерацию. А иначе добавляем в массив.

Перед добавлением надо посортовать, чтобы можно было убирать дубликаты.

```js
function comb(arr, depth) {
  const res = new Set();
  if (depth === 0) res.add([]);
  else {
    for (const pc of comb(arr, depth - 1)) {
      for (const e of arr) {
        if (pc.indexOf(e) !== -1) break;
        res.add([e, ...pc].sort((a, b) => a - b));
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log([...comb([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)].map(e => [e, e.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)]));
```

Comment: Вот теперь вижу - действительно кортежи)

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло